# addView only showing after void end

Tags: android

I use this void to append TextViews in a log-like process to display it to the user:

```
static void addlog(Activity innercont, String txt)
    {
        TextView tadd = new TextView(innercont);
        tadd.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tadd.setText(txt);
        Log.i(TAG,"addlog: "+txt);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.addView(tadd);

        ScrollView scro = (ScrollView) innercont.findViewById(R.id.ScrollView1);
        scro.removeAllViews();
        scro.addView(layout);

        innercont.setContentView(scro);
    }
```

I know that most of the things are useless, but this is my attempt at the moment.

**The problem**

At first (MainActivity-onCreate) i add an initialization entry using this void - it works.
Afterwards, i have a function (private class navigata extends WebViewClient) that calls another function (custom void) that has a lot of entries using this function.
None of them become displayed until the function is finished (and that takes a lot of time), what makes the whole log useless (no one needs a log that you can only see after everything is finished).

**So my question is**: How can i do sth like pausing the function so that the textviews can be added?

Comment: Use a separate `Thread` for the work or look at `AsyncTask` which is designed for long-running operations

Comment: Why the downvote?? Please provide a reason so i can improve the post! @Butscher: I'll tr, thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Michael Butscher, i solved the problem using Threads.

Therefore, i modified the original addlog-function like this:

```
static void addlog(Activity innercont, String txt)
    {
        if (innercont.findViewById(255) != null)
        {
            TextView tadd = (TextView) innercont.findViewById(255);
            String atmtxt = (String) tadd.getText();
            atmtxt = atmtxt+"\n"+txt;
            tadd.setText(atmtxt);
            return;
        }

        TextView tadd = new TextView(innercont);
        tadd.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tadd.setText(txt);
        tadd.setId(255);

        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.addView(tadd);

        ScrollView scro = (ScrollView) innercont.findViewById(R.id.ScrollView1);
        scro.removeAllViews();
        scro.addView(layout);

        innercont.setContentView(scro);
    }
```

And had the main work doing in a thread with its own addlog-function, which uses `View.post` to access the UI without blocking it.

```
final TextView tadd = (TextView) cont.findViewById(255);
        tadd.setText("");
        //Log.i(TAG, "get lists" );

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void addlog2(final Activity cont, final String txt)
            {
                tadd.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        String atmtxt = (String) tadd.getText();
                        atmtxt = atmtxt+"\n"+txt;
                        tadd.setText(atmtxt);
                    }
                });
            }


            public void run() {
                addlog2(cont,"log text");
                                //...
              }
      }).start();
```